# what is the meaning of @ in bison code

Tags: bison

I am reading some legacy bison code, and it has a rule like the following:

```
function_decl: name body function_end
     { if($3 != $1->id) {
           yyerror(@3, "error: function name does not match end label");
       }
     }
;
```

I understand that $i refers to the value returned by each token in the rule. But what does @i represent? I tried googling for it, but did not get any relevant hit.

Comment: Documentation? http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Table-of-Symbols.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@n` is the "location" corresponding to the symbol `$n`. Using any `@` reference in a bison grammar automatically enables locations, but it is still the responsibility of the scanner to generate the information (in the global variable `yylloc`).

A location is a range of positions representing the start and end of the terminal or non-terminal. By default, it is kept in a `struct` with four fields: `first_line`, `first_column`, `last_line`, `last_column`.

Location objects for non-terminals are automatically created by the bison parser; by default, the location range extends from the start of the first symbol to the end of the last symbol.

For more information, see the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Locations).